# Using getPosition() with Google Advanced markers

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why "getPosition()" doesn't work with the new Google map Advanced markers?

Below is a link to a test page where "getPosition()" works fine with a legacy marker, while the Advanced marker gets an "Uncaught TypeError: marker2.getPosition is not a function" error message.

Refer to the console.log for results.

Test page:

https://whowillbethenextonline.com/advanced-marker-get-position.html

Thanks,

Bennie

P.S. I tried all kinds of things, and looked everywhere, but haven't been able to figure it out, nor find an answer online.

P.P.S. Finally! After looking at the code for this Google maps tutorial "Make markers draggable" example,

[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/advanced-markers-draggable],

I changed "marker2.getPosition()" to "marker2.position.lat" and "marker2.position.lng" and the remote Advance marker button worked!

See example page: [ https://whowillbethenextonline.com/advanced-marker-get-position-2.html ].

I tried "marker.position.lat" and "marker.position.lng" for the legacy marker and got something other than the lat and lng, as you will be able to see in your console.log() gizmo.

Answer (score 1):

Old Markers (Legacy) support `getPosition()` method to get their coordinates.

As Google introduced AdvancedMarkerElement now marker location coordinates can be retrieved using just `.position`

Example:

Old Marker elements
`marker.getPosition()`

New Advanced Marker `marker.position`

Comment: Thank you, kerri, for your answer. I see that you are from Latvia. Here is a web page about Latvia that you might enjoy: https://whowillbethenextonline.com/destination-3-mo.html Bennie

Answer (score 0):

After updating to advanced markers I had a very similar issue, with the same error. In the end I had to add the lat and long into .position

Here is the original line which didn't work with advanced markers

```
map.panTo(clickedMarker.getPosition());
```

Here is my new line of code that worked

```
map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(clickedMarker.position.lat, clickedMarker.position.lng));
```